# Convolution of measures and Fourier transform of a finite measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I am reading a book on Harmonic Analysis on $\mathbb R^n$. It needs some facts about finite measure space $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$, which is said to be the dual of $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$. In this space we could define Fourier transform, convolution operation, ...

I am looking for a good book which is dealing with properties on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$, with all these facts about in details. So which books should I read? Do those books give the settings which we could generalize to locally compact  abelian groups?

Comment: Did you find a good book eventually? I am looking for a similar reference which is covering Fourier transforms of finite Borel measures, convolution etc. ...

Comment: The Fourier transform on $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ seen as a (tempered) distribution ? @user190080

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/computing-convolutions-of-measures/

Comment: @user1952009 not exactly. I am looking specifically for a reference for Fourier transform on the space of finite Borel measures (I guess it also sometimes called Fourier–Stieltjes transform).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro so far Tao's blog actually has been my primary source...it's good, but it's not a monograph which covers this in depth. Thanks for posting it anyway. I was looking for something like Katznelson's "An introduction to harmonic analysis" but with a deeper focus on the measure side.